# UIBarButtonItem disable animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an UIBarButtonItem, which is a non-clickable logo. How do I disable the touch animation for this logo?

I have tried getting at the view:

```
        let view = self.appTitle.performSelector(Selector("view")).takeRetainedValue() as? UIView
        view?.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

but then the app crashes.

The `UIBarButtonItem` is inside a `UiToolbar`, created in a storyboard.

Comment: what is touch animation , you are mean by that is image for both normal and highlighted state ?

Comment: are you tried for disable the user interaction of button

Comment: What you are doing seems over complicated and probably wrong, if its in `navController` then call `tittle/right/left/barButtonItem` in `navigationItem`, else then include where the bar button is lying in

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the button does not have the "userInteractionEnabled" property

Comment: @MikeAlter when I touch the button, it gets a different color. I don't want this effect. I tried `self.appTitle.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "footer"), forState: .Highlighted, barMetrics: .Default)`, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
self.appTitle.customView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "footer"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want UIBarButtonItem be don't clicked use

```
barBtnItem.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.TransitionCrossDissolve, .ShowHideTransitionViews]
        UIView.transitionWithView(#yourUIBarButtonItem outlet, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            self.#yourUIBarButtonItem outlet.enabled = false
            }, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

If your UIBarButtonItem is in NavigationItem then first assign it to leftBarButtonItem or rightBarButtonItem and then set **enabled** property of UIBarButtonItem to **NO** in objective-c and **false** in swift

**Objective-C:**

```
    UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"];
    UIButton *menu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menu.frame = CGRectMake( 10, 0, menuImage.size.width, menuImage.size.height);
    [menu addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [menu setImage:menuImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menu];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

**Swift:**

```
    var menuImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "menu")!
    var menu: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    menu.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, menuImage.size.width, menuImage.size.height)
    menu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleBack), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    menu.setImage(menuImage, forState: .Normal)
    var backButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menu)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = false
```